# Mocking a getter than returns an array using Mockolate

Tags: actionscript-3, unit-testing, mockolate

I am writing a unit test for a function that calls a getter on my object. The getter should return an array, but I get an exception thrown:

```
Error: No Expectation defined for Invocation:[FloxyInvocation invocationType=GETTER name="getterName" arguments=[]]
```

I mocked my getter with:

```
mock(object).getter("getterName").returns(new Array()).once();
```

My getter is defined in the object interface:

```
function get getterName():Array;
```

Do I need to rewrite the getter function or my mock statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was mocking the interface of the object instead of and object of the class that implements the interface.